# How to scrollTo on page load on desktop and mobile safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Right now I have this code which works fine on Chrome.

```js
// scroll on page load
scrollWindowToElement(document.querySelector('.something'))

/**
 * Scroll to specific element.
 */

function scrollWindowToElement(el) {
  let pos = getTop(el)
  window.scrollTo(0, pos)
  document.body.scrollTo(0, pos)
}

/**
 * Get top position of an element.
 */

function getTop(el) {
  let top = 0
  while (el && !isNaN(el.offsetTop)) {
    top += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop
    el = el.offsetParent
  }
  return top
}
```

```html
<div class='onething'>hello</div>
<div class='something'>world</div>
<div class='anotherthing'>foo</div>
```

The question is why this isn't working on Safari (desktop or mobile) and potentially other browsers, and how to get it working (without jQuery, i.e. with vanilla JavaScript) in all *modern* browsers.

As a tangential note, the element and document.body can both be with `opacity: 0` if that matters, but they are not `display: none`, so in Chrome at least this works fine.

Do I need to be doing something like [this](https://muffinman.io/ios-safari-get-bounding-client-rect-bug/)?

Comment: Can you describe where you are putting the script? In the head or body, before or after the div? Also, is that the only script running?

Comment: I am putting the script at the end of the body after everything. Even if I set a `setTimeout(fn, 1)` it doesn't work. Only works if I do something like `setTimeout(fn, 100)` for some reason. This is the only script running and that's all it really does (there's a few more things but unrelated).

Comment: I suspect what happened is that the script executes before the page is fully rendered with styles (positioning). To solve this, you might just need something like:
`window.onload = function() { 
    scrollWindowToElement(document.querySelector('.something'));
};`

Comment: I don't want the page to visibly scroll to the element, will that occur in your solution? I want it to simply appear at that element from the start when you see the first content.

Comment: There will be no animation. The scroll position should simply jump to the element's position on load.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, and I tried even opening the dev console in safari and setting it way after page load, and it doesn't work. `window.scrollTo(x, y)` and `document.body.scrollTo(x, y)`. Does it matter that I have `html { overflow: hidden }` in my CSS? Because the page still scrolls if I use the trackpad like normal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197134/discussion-between-lance-pollard-and-light).

Comment: Please see my answer to see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

First, you should use `load` event, either by setting `window.onload` or by adding an event listener as shown below:

```
    // scroll on page load
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        scrollWindowToElement(document.querySelector('.something'));
    });
```

Second, your scrolling function should only need to use `window.scrollTo`

```
   /**
   * Scroll to specific element.
   */
   function scrollWindowToElement(el) {
      let pos = getTop(el);
      window.scrollTo(0, pos);
   }
```

Third, your `getTop` implementation may not give you the correct position. The simplest way:

```
   /**
    * Get top position of an element.
    */
   function getTop(el) {
      return window.scrollY + el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
   }
```

Take note also that this code would only serve to change the scroll position on page load.

For page refreshes, many browsers tend to remember the old scroll position and restore (by force-changing) it after window load. So if you want to overwrite the page refresh restore scroll behavior, you have to use delay your `scrollWindowToElement` call within your load event listener. Test some sensible values for `setTimeout`. A delay of 100ms or so should work well for most cases.

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't work :/, even with setTimeout or manually doing it in the debugger/web console.

Comment: Does calling `scrollWindowToElement(document.querySelector('.something'));` work in console?

Comment: `window.scrollTo(0, 100)` doesn't work on a window either, with 10000 height.

Comment: If the page is not scrolling, it could be because of your CSS. Ensure that both `html` and `body` are not `overflow:hidden`. You may set `body` to `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;`